# Cannot apply attribute class 'Setup' because it is abstract NUnit

Tags: nunit

error CS0653: Cannot apply attribute class 'Setup' because it is abstract

You're setting up some NUnit tests and you can't figure out why you are getting this error.

Other tests are using 'Setup' in the same way what could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After scratching my head on this and many googles that didn't get to the crux of the issue, I finally found the [NUnit documentation page here.](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/setup.html)

```
'Setup' is incorrect.

'SetUp' is correct.
```

I found it frustrating that searching the error message did not immediately come to the documentation or anything useful for fixing the problem, so I am making this Question and Answer to hopefully help others find the solution faster and not waste as much time.

Comment: Noone should expect a CSharp error message to take them to NUnit docs! But it's good to remind people to read the docs for whatever software they use. :-)